# Can the opponents see my stacks on the Dragon Slayer buff?

Tags: league-of-legends

[Patch 4.20 introduced a full dragon rework](http://euw.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/patch/patch-420-notes#patch-dragon-rewards)

> DRAGON SLAYER Killing Dragon now gives your team a permanent stacking
>   buff called "Dragon Slayer":
>
> - Dragon's Might (1 stack): +8% total attack damage and ability power
> - Dragon's Dominance (2 stacks): +15% damage to minions and monsters
> - Dragon's Flight (3 stacks): +5% movement speed
> - Dragon's Wrath (4 stacks): +15% damage to turrets and buildings
> - Aspect of the Dragon (5 stacks, repeatable): Doubles all other bonuses and your attacks burn enemies for 150 true damage over 5
>     seconds. Lasts 180 seconds.

**Can the enemies see my Dragon Slayer stacks?** This would always give them the time when the dragon was slain. even when they don't see it or it was obvious that it has been slain.

Comment: I would guess they can see the buff, haven't played new patch though.

Comment: @Damek well.... me neither. but maybe someone did.

Comment: Well, unless you happen to be watching their buff stacks as the dragon goes down, you won't know exactly WHEN the dragon kill was, only that it had occured.

Comment: @Psychemaster If you are constanly watching the buff's of the enemy, and let's say you go back shopping and then the enemie team kills dragon. Even though you didn't see dragon die you still see the increased buff. Thus giving you a pretty accurate timer.

Answer (score 6):

You can even see it in the score board... so it doesnt really matter if you see the buff on the enemy champion

[image]

Allied team has 0 dragons slayn

Enemy team has 2 stacks on the dragon buff

Comment: Interesting, even if you didn't have sight on drag while it's being slain, you could watch the scoreboard to get the timer.

Comment: @DevonParsons exactly... i don't like it...